# What kind of speech synthesis is "HMM synthesis"?

Tags: speech-synthesis, applied-linguistics

The Wikipedia page on synthetic speech claims:

> The two primary technologies generating synthetic speech waveforms are
>   concatenative synthesis and formant synthesis.

It then goes on to describe those technologies, as well as a separate section on "HMM-synthesis" almost as an afterthought:

> HMM-based synthesis is a synthesis method based on hidden Markov
>   models, also called Statistical Parametric Synthesis. In this system,
>   the frequency spectrum (vocal tract), fundamental frequency (voice
>   source), and duration (prosody) of speech are modeled simultaneously
>   by HMMs. Speech waveforms are generated from HMMs themselves based on
>   the maximum likelihood criterion.[34]

The link at the end takes the reader to a webpage without much description of what hmm-synthesis is. But maybe those of you more familiar with speech synthesis have some insight.

Is hmm-synthesis Concatenative synthesis, Formant synthesis, or something else altogether? I am boggled so any help would be great. Just want to get an idea of the kinds of speech synthesis so I understand better the overall strategies for synthesis speech generation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HMM-based systems and concatenative waveform-based unit-selection systems are similar in that they both involve the use of a large database of recorded human speech, and they both involve concatenating stored units to construct something that results in a whole output utterance.

However, whereas waveform-based unit-selection systems store actual waveforms from the database and concatenate those waveforms, **HMM-based systems store HMMs that have been trained on the database and concatenate the HMMs.** These HMM "units" are used to construct a single HMM for the desired output utterance. A set of parameter values is generated from that utterance HMM, and a synthesizer synthesizes the output based on those parameter values.

You can find many resources for further reading by Googling *speech synthesis based on hidden markov models*.